# Running a command with os.system(A) produces different output then running A in shell

Tags: python, shell, unix, scripting

I have a hex to binary converter that I am using in a Python script...

```
os.system("./HexToBinary " + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_hex " + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_binary")
```

If I run my python script on file A_hex, it produces file A_binary.

But if I run this command directly in the command-line, on file AA_hex it produces AA_binary. But A_binary and AA_binary differ!

```
diff example_python example_shell 
Binary files example_python and example_shell differ
```

The version produced by the python os.system call is missing a chunk of data from the end. It seems that it just gets cut off.

I'm kinda stumped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it is needed, but try wait, http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.wait

also, check the output of system, it may help tell you if something is wrong

Comment: os.system prints out 256. How do I use os.wait? I put a os.wait() right after os.system(A), but the interpreter coughs up OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes

Comment: @aaa [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) waits for the subprocess to be finished.

Comment: @mark `os.system` returns this exit code of the child process (not always true though). You can't use it for `os.wait`.

Comment: @khachik Yeah. I've seen behavior like this when I forgot to close file descriptors, but that is handled all in the C++ compiled HexToBinary.

Comment: @mark people say "`os.system` is not good use `subprocess.Popen` instead". You can try it (but I'm not where is the problem and how it can be fixed).

Comment: @mark it might be obvious, but can you print the command and run it as is?

Comment: @aaa I do print the command to verify it is correct. I don't get what you mean by "run it as is"

Comment: @ khachik - I can't seem to get subprocess.Popen working even after looking at online documentation.